# Having Only Admin Be Able to Create a New User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have devise installed and configured on my rails 3 project and I want to make it so that only admins can create/edit users.  How can I edit the devise controllers to accomplish this?

Comment: You might want to checkout https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization - there is also an old railscast on it - http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sorted this out previously. I remember it being a pain but it does work. It requires [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).

Given that an administrator is defined with an `admin` boolean on the `User` model:

**user.rb:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessor :current_password
  attr_accessible :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :email, :remember_me, :admin

end

class Ability
    include CanCan::Ability

    def initialize(user)
    can :manage, :all if user.admin
  end
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  params[:user].delete(:password) if params[:user][:password].blank?
  params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation) if params[:user][:password].blank? and params[:user][:password_confirmation].blank?
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated "+@user.name
    redirect_to users_path
  else
    render :action => 'edit'
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, :path => "d"

devise_scope :user do
  get '/sign_in' => 'devise/sessions#new'
  get '/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
end

resources :users, :controller => "users"
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  after_filter :user_activity

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def admin?
    self.admin == true
  end

  def authenticate_admin
    redirect_to :new_user_session_path unless current_user && current_user.admin?
  end

  private

  def user_activity
    current_user.try :touch
  end

end
```

**application_helper.rb**

```
def resource_name
  :user
end

def resource
  @resource ||= User.new
end

def devise_mapping
  @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
end
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [CanCan](https://rubygems.org/gems/cancan) for that.

First, you'll [define abilities](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities) like `:read`, `:create`, `:update` and `:destroy` and assign them to user roles by using something like:

```
if user.admin?
  can :manage, :all
end
```

Then, you'll [check those abilities](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Checking-Abilities) by checking whether the user has permissions to create/edit users by using something like `if can? :create, User`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only to allow admins to create users you could write something like

```
class uUsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
     #validate if the current user is an admin 
  end
end
```

**But** the more standard, flexible way is to use a gem like [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan), which personally I would prefer :)